# How to get the Owl 6 achievement?

Tags: achievements, year-walk

The Owl 6 achievement is described as:

> The owls sing a song that they learned in the lobby of a castle on a remote island.

It's more or less obvious it can be achieved by playing a specific song with the owls next to the big tree. But what is the song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [Achievement Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=235463934) by [Cassel](http://steamcommunity.com/id/cassel), the combination can be found in another game, [Device 6](http://simogo.com/work/device-6/) (unfortunately only available on iOS), and is:

> LRRLLLRLRL

(where L means "left owl" and R means "right owl")